# Is there a way to tell robocopy to report in its log how many files it has overwritten?

Tags: windows, robocopy, copy

I'm using Robocopy with the /MIR option to backup some directories periodically, and I would like it to output a log in which the summary can tell me how many files were overwritten (not just copied or skipped). Is that possible?

Comment: What about parsing the log file afterwards to filter for the information you want?

Comment: @music2myear: Yes, that is possible but would be very long, especially when you have a log file containing some 300K+ file entries or even more ... The best thing would be to have it somehow in the summary. I was thinking the /X option could work but I found out it did not.

Comment: Scanning of one large text file should be quite feasible.

Comment: I'm not aware of Robocopy having this function built in. Doing a post script run process on the log is the best way to go, and even in a lower powered machine should be quite efficient when written properly. Managing text files is not difficult for a CPU.